# Preencher um select via jquery no cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, json

Fiz um pouco mais fácil, mas ainda não está funcionando.
Ao invés de montar tudo no javascript, na minha action eu monto todo html e no javascript eu somente passo o html montado para meu select.

```
function MostraPrograma(){
 var _valorSelect = document.getElementById("CursoEscolaId").value;     
 $.post('/novas/mostra_programa/'+_valorSelect),$("#CursoNewAddForm").serialize(), function(data){                          
    $("#rowIdChata").html(data);

 }
```

}

e essa é minha view:

```
<?php
 if($info_campus == 0){
echo 'Não existem tipos de curso para esta escola';   
}else{
foreach($info_campus as $info){?>
<option value="<?=$info['CursoCampus']['id']?>"><?=$info['CursoCampus']['nome']?></option><?  php }} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua aplicação precisará realizar duas operações:

1) Realizar o parse da string no formato JSON para javascript, existem varias formas na internet, seja com Javascript puro ou com bibliotecas, mas faço assim:

Obs. Troquei o `$.post` por `$.get` acho que é desse método que você precisa.

```js
     $.get('/novas/mostra_programa/'+_a, function(data){
         var opcoes = (new Function("return " + data +";"))();
     });
```

2) Realizar um loop e montar os options

```js
   $.get('/novas/mostra_programa/'+_a, function(data){
      var opcoes = (new Function("return " + data +";"))();

      var sel = document.getElementById('{ID DO SELECT}');
      var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

      for(var i = 0; i < opcoes.length; i++){
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = opcoes[i].CursoCampus.nome;
        opt.value = opcoes[i].CursoCampus.id;
        fragment.appendChild(opt);
     }

      sel.appendChild(fragment.cloneNode(true));
  });
```

Comment: editei, fiz um pouco mais fácil, mas ainda não funciona, me parece que quando ele dá post não volta pra função, e nada que está dentro do meu post executa.

Comment: aplica o passo 1, e usa o console.log para indentificar se está ocorrendo como previsto. Depois, aplica o passo 2 e do mesmo modo utiliza o console.log pra ver se também está procedendo como desejado

Comment: fiz uma pequena modificacao no passo 2 também, no trecho -> fragment.cloneNode(true)

Comment: o problema era que eu estava executando a função `$post` errada, eu estava fazendo `$post(url),function` e o certo é `$post(url,function{});`

Comment: Nossa, nem tinha percebido este equívoco. Mas que bom que você mesmo conseguiu encontrar. Pode estar certo que assim, você aprendeu muuito. Boa sorte aí

Comment: Muito Obrigado, demoramos, mas conseguimos.

Comment: É isso ai, boa sorte!